# How do I save data in related tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a question. I created a table with many to many relationships as below. What code should I write so that I can enter multiple categories when adding a product to the database?
I would be glad if you explain with an example.
For example, I can enter product.name information with the name information I received from the user, but I do not know how to save data in the relevant tables.

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
        
}


public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public string Url { get; set; }       
    public double? Price { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; }         
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsHome { get; set; }

    public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
}
   

public class ProductCategory
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Google is your first friend. Search up EF and Many-to-many relationships and you'll have all the info you need. For a start I'd recommend initializing your collections so that they are ready to use when you create new objects. `public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();`

Comment: I know how to create a table but I don't know how to save data to a linked table.

Comment: What have you tried? The code examples in the EF documentation cover off how to insert records using the entities and the DbContext.  EF generally handles linking tables, it's not like you have to add rows separately to DbSets. StackOverflow is a Q&A site where you can put up and example of the code you are working on and ask how to get a desired behaviour vs. what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert them by the join table like this:

```
var product = new Product { Name = "AA" };
var categories = new List<Category>
{
    new Category{ Name = "a"},
    new Category{ Name = "b"},
    new Category{ Name = "c"},
};

foreach (var category in categories)
{
    _context.ProductCategory.Add(
    new ProductCategory
    {
        Product = product,
        Category = category
    });

}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version you are using. with EF Core 5.o find an example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew

Models:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}


public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsHome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

Or If you are using EE 6 or EF Core 3.1 then your models should be like:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategorie { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsHome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategorie { get; set; }

}

public class ProductCategory
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

For inserting data to Many-Many tables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0
then please look at the section:**Seed database with test data**

Comment: I know how to create tables. What I want to learn is how can I save data to linked tables I created using linq?